# Wireshark Does Not Recognize Kafka Protocol

Tags: networking, apache-kafka, wireshark, pcap

I am trying to analyze Kafka packages, but Wireshark is not recognizing Kafka protocol for some reason. Instead of something like this:

[image]

I get everything as plain TCP:
[image]

I made sure that the protocol is enabled and the correct port is set.
[image]

I also tried to use `Analyze/Decode As...` without any success.

I am using Wireshark v3.6.6

How can I make it work?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see? Keys and values will remain byte arrays, for example, not plaintext and clients send records within batches, not one at a time https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_common

Comment: The message is exactly what I am expecting to see. Something like this => https://snipboard.io/CfzTAu.jpg

Comment: Also, I want to correlate some events, like consumers leaving a group, with logs.

Comment: I'm not sure about the group protocol records, but with the [Kafka filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/k/kafka.html) applied, you should be able to get `kafka.message_value`

Comment: That's the problem, I cannot use any Kafka filters as Wireshark does not recognize the protocol :(